# Ilgenerator: push default initialized System.Nullable to Stack

Tags: c#, cil

I am currently trying to write code where the user can initialize selected properties of an class with a default value (used as part of an SQL to C# mapping project).
The following code gives an VerificationException that it could destabilize the runtime:

```
private static void InitWithNullable(ILGenerator il, MethodInfo setter, Type objType)
{
    var local = il.DeclareLocal(objType);

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, local);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, objType);

    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, setter, null);
}
```

One of the properties is of Type `System.Nullable<MyEnum>`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Without the `MyEnum?` it works?

Comment: Are you putting `ldarg.0` at the beginning of the method to load the `this` and `ret` at the end of the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InitObj` should be:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, objType);
```

From the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj(v=vs.105).aspx):

> The following Emit method overload can use the initobj opcode:
>
> ILGenerator.Emit(OpCode, Type)

And the `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, objType);` is probably wrong... I would need to see the whole generated code. And you need to load the *this* (that is a `ldarg.0`) somewhere...

Probably:

```
var local = il.DeclareLocal(objType);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 0); // Used by the OpCodes.callvirt

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, objType);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local.Index);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, setter, null);
```

Like in the [TryRoslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:%3Eilr/A4VwRgNglgxgBAUwHYgLZwGIHstwLABQA3oQL6FyX4GiSxwwQCGAzi3AMLUkFVy3R42LAH44AISYAnOETgBzBABcA3HBbK15XlQH0oSJZigAvWQs3rL2vhV3hBcAG5YoAEzgBJJFCUAKAEpqPh4+PkkZAF44NwQAMyYQCH9hEQCVOzC4AHpszLCMUzho2ISk/wMldPztUiA=) decompiled sample.

Comment: It probably is the missing object pointer. The MethodInfo is taken from a function which is declared outside in a different object (type is Func<IDataReader, int, TEnum>). So I also need to push the target of the func at the stack? How would I do that?

Comment: @PeterSchojer If it is a parameter of the generated function, then a `OpCodes.Ldarg, 1`.

Comment: You were definitley right. It has nothing to do with the enum. It is somehow System.Nullable in general were I am doing sth wrong. I have marked your answer as valid already. I must have another bug somewhere else

Comment: Nearly fixed,  except initilaizing with  Nullable<T>() I have posted a full sample as answer (too long for comment) but I don't really see where I went wrong. Code is the same for the single DateTime property as you recommended in your answer.

Comment: Found it: Instead of `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);` I had to use `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local.LocalIndex);`

Comment: @PeterSchojer You are right :-) The TryRoslyn WAS using `Ldloc, 0` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of setting a single property to either the loaded value or to a default value when DBNULL is returned

```
    public void MiniTest()
    {
        IDbConnection con = Session.Connection;
        var method = new DynamicMethod("test", null,
            new Type[] { typeof(IDataReader), typeof(MyOrder) });
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        var defaultLabel = il.DefineLabel();
        var endLabel = il.DefineLabel();
        // generate isdbnull check
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //push reader
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0); //push idx on stack
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethod("IsDBNull"), null);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, defaultLabel);
        //stack now empty
        //do the read call and assign the value
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); //push data
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //push reader
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0); //push idx on stack
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethod("GetDateTime"), null); // call r.Get...(idx) and push result on stack
        //stack is data, DateTime
        var ctor = typeof(DateTime?).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(DateTime) });
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor); // create the system.nullable and push it on stack
        // stack is data, DateTime?
        var prop = LinqExt.GetPropertyFast<MyOrder, DateTime?>(x => x.Shipment);
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetSetMethod(), null); // call d.Property setter
        //consumes data + Datetime? value
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Br, endLabel);
        il.MarkLabel(defaultLabel);
        //we start with an empty stack here
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); //push data
        var local = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(DateTime?));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, typeof(DateTime?));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local.LocalIndex);
        //stack is now data, new DateTime?()
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetSetMethod(), null);
        //stack empty
        il.MarkLabel(endLabel);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var action = (Action<IDataReader, MyOrder>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IDataReader, MyOrder>));
        List<MyOrder> data = new List<MyOrder>();
        using (var reader = con.Query(
@"Select o.Shipment
 from TestOrder o
 where o.Order_Id = :id",
            0,
            new { id = 1 }))
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                MyOrder u = new MyOrder();
                action(reader, u);
                data.Add(u);
            }
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(1, data.Count);
        Assert.IsNull( data[0].Shipment);
    }
```

This should translate to the following action:

```
Action<IDataReader, MyOrder> action = (r, o) =>
        {
            if (r.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                o.Shipment = null;
            }
            else
            {
                o.Shipment = r.GetDateTime(0);
            }
        };
```

And further simplified to only include the set to null for System.Nullable:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MicroTest2()
    {
        var action = InitWithNull<ExtUser, int?>(x => x.NIntId, "MicroTest2Impl");

        ExtUser u = new ExtUser();
        u.NIntId = 1;
        action( u);

        Assert.IsNull(u.NIntId);
    }

    private static Action<TObject> InitWithNull<TObject, TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TObject,TProperty>> property, string name)
    {

        var method = new DynamicMethod(name, null,
            new Type[] { typeof(TObject) });

        var il = method.GetILGenerator();

        var prop = LinqExt.GetPropertyFast(property);
        //we start with an empty stack here

        var local = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(TProperty));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //push data
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, typeof(TProperty));

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local.LocalIndex);
        //stack is now data, new TProperty?()
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetSetMethod(), null);
        //stack empty
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var action = (Action<TObject>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TObject>));
        return action;
    }
```